# Compute this complex limit

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I am having difficulties in proving that the below limit exists:
$$\LARGE{ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k+x)^{x + i\cdot t}}}{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^{x + i\cdot t}}}}$$ where $x \in (0,1)$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}_+$

I would like to have an upper bound on the modulus of this thing, for instance as a function of $t,x$.

### My observations:

for $x = 0$ the above is $1$, for $t = 0$ one can use Stolz-Cesaro and prove that the limit is $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{n}{n+x} \right)^{x} = 1$. For $x = 1$ one obtains something like $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n - 1}{S_n}$ where $S_n$ is the denominator of the above limit. Again, if $|S_n| \to \infty$ then the limit apporoaches $1$ in modulus. How can I prove this for the general case? If the function is holomorphic, then can we use the identity theorem for holomorphic functions to say that the limit is $1$ for all $t$ since it is $1$ for all $\{x + i \cdot t | t = 0, x \in (0,1) \}$ (which has an accumulation point)

Comment: In the numerator, write $$\frac{1}{(k+x)^{x+it}} = \frac{1}{k^{x+it}} - (x+it)\int_0^x \frac{du}{(k+u)^{1+x+it}}\,.$$ The second is smaller in modulus than $x\lvert x+it\rvert\cdot \frac{1}{k^{1+x}}$, so the sum over that remains bounded. Then show $\lvert S_n\rvert \to \infty$.

Comment: Edit: I enlarged the formula, because it was difficult to read it.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for the hint! Can you also give another hint at proving that $|S_n| \to \infty$ ?

Comment: You can use the Euler-Maclaurin formula, or Euler's sum formula, or Abel's summation formula. Anything that gives you control over the error you make when you replace the sum with an integral.

Comment: another way to think of this is that for large $N$ depending on $t$ the denominator is $N^{1-x-it}/(1-x-it)$ plus bounded terms and the numerator is $(N+x)^{1-x-it}/(1-x-it)$ plus bounded terms and $|N^{1-x-it}|=N^{1-x} \to \infty$ for $0 <x<1$

Answer (score -1):

For $x = 0$: $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\sum\limits ^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^{it}}}{\sum\limits ^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^{it}}} =1$.

For $x = 1$: $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\sum\limits ^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{( k+1)^{1+it}}}{\sum\limits ^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^{1+it}}} =\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\frac{1}{2^{1+it}} +\frac{1}{3^{1+it}} +\frac{1}{4^{1+it}} +\cdots }{\frac{1}{1^{1+it}} +\frac{1}{2^{1+it}} +\frac{1}{3^{1+it}} +\cdots } = 1$, because of $\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{1^t + 2^t + 3^t + \cdots}{2^t + 3^t + \cdots} = 1$.

Then $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\sum\limits ^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{( k+x)^{x+it}}}{\sum\limits ^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^{x+it}}} = 1$.